# Java: Sockets - DataStream really slow

Tags: java, performance, sockets

I'm using just normal DataInputStream and DataOutputStream in threads for receive, send (with accept on server) to make a game, but it is really slow. >5 seconds lag.

Here is how I made it (most of it looks like that):

(dos is DataOutputStream)

```
dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dos.writeFloat(dp.x);
dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dos.writeFloat(dp.y);
dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dos.writeUTF(dp.username);
```

And for Input (this one is in server) I use:

(dis is DataInputStream, it's in a for loop so i is for each player)

```
dis = new DataInputStream(list_sockets.get(i).getInputStream());
x = dis.readFloat();
dis = new DataInputStream(list_sockets.get(i).getInputStream());
y = dis.readFloat();
dis = new DataInputStream(list_sockets.get(i).getInputStream());
username = dis.readUTF();
```

So it is really slow, but I don't know why :(
Please help?

EDIT: Every operation (send, accept, receive) has it's own daemon thread.

Comment: Why are you repeatedly creating new DataInput/OutputStreams?

Comment: I don't know. That's how I saw other people do it online. Is that a big problem?

Comment: It's a big waste of time and resources.

Comment: Okay, but if I create it only at the beggining will multiplayer be faster?

Comment: No one can tell with the code you posted. It shouldn't be slower, that's about all that can be said.

Comment: Well that is basically how the whole thing looks, there's not much more. It's just sending and receiving position. Without complicated for loops or anything.

Comment: Well, just try removing all the stuff that's not necessary and try it out. Only _you_ can measure if the performance difference is significant or not.

Comment: I take it your application is the only thing that's slow, but other communication with that computer is fine, right?

Comment: Yes we both have perfect internet and live close

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Repeatedly creating `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` instances is not good for performance.

However, I suspect that a **more important** performance issue is that you are reading and writing without any Java-side buffering.  This means that each read / write call is making one (and possibly many) syscalls to read data.  System calls are a couple of orders of magnitude slower than ordinary Java method calls.

You need to wrap the Socket input stream in a `BufferedInputStream` and the output stream in a `BufferedOutputStream`, and then wrap these in the Data streams.  (Note that when you do this, it becomes more important that you `flush` the `DataOutputStream` at the end of each message, or series of messages.

---

> Do I write a few info, and then flush after every each write?

Like I said above, you flush at the end of each message, or each sequence of messages.  Each flush on your buffered output stream will result in a syscall, assuming there is data in the buffer to be flushed.  If you flush on every write you are (probably) doing unnecessary syscalls.

It is up to you to figure out where your protocol's message boundaries ought to be.  It depends entirely on the details of the data you are sending / receiving, and the way it is processed.

Comment: OOOOOH! Thanks, so BufferedStream didn't work for me because I didn't flush?

Comment: Do I write a few info, and then flush or flash after every each write?

Comment: (I wouldn't recommend flashing.  You can get arrested for that :-)

Comment: I mean, flush after a few, or flush after every write. Lol

Comment: @IvanDonat In request/response protocols you really only need to flush before each read. Think about it.

Comment: More generally, careful analysis of the protocols and your implementation of them will tell you whether and when a flush is required.

Answer (score 2):

Like you say you have a for loop and create a new data input/output stream for every iteration in the loop. This will cause a massive overhead.

You should have 1 data input and output stream for each client (on a seperate thread) and then get the users input by looping round the stream building up the input until the Input Stream is empty.

Answer (score 1):

When by "slow" you only mean network lagging, then you should "flush" your stream to enforce transportation of non full buffers.

Addition:

Even so you will get a "working draft" going on like this, take into account that a well designed communication protocol contains all kinds of bells and whistles around the plain command.. Question arise like

- Exception handling
- Sequencing
- Authentication
- Integrity check (avoid cheating, replay,...)
- Extensability (new commands, use explicit command object)
- Real Time handling
- and for sure a lot of others...

There are some frameworks around to keep you from that burden.

Comment: After each single "command" is finished (e.g. if a command sequence is three int's, after three ints...).

Comment: I still don't get it. Can you please edit your thing and add an example of writing a few ints or something and where to put flushes?